# Doesn't build-time integration of micro frontends, defeat the purpose of a micro frontend?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, micro-frontend

I mean, if I have to build & load my whole code at first load, why go into micro-frontends?

I think build-time integration is beneficial only to say you have a large team and you want to divide them and make them work as independently as possible. But if i talk about the performance issues what improvement do they offer?

Comment: I am talking in terms of comparison with real-time integration